# Parsing RFC 4180 CSV with GOTOs

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

One of my data-import tools needs to support CSV files. I thought that parsing CSV is such a simple task that I didn't want to use any any external libraries for that. So here is one more [RFC 4180](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Standardization) CSV parser. This one however works with two `goto`s.

---

I don't preach *never use `goto`* because I find there are situations in which it's useful. In this implementation it allows me to reduce code repetition by having only a single `yield return` and resetting all variables before parsing each line. Without the `goto` it would require one `yiled return` inside the loop and another one at the end for the last line. Resetting flags would also need to be done twice - initilization before the loop and then after each line.

The parser does not use any `continue`s and `if else`s. I find they are confusing so I'd rather nest one more `if/else` than break the flow multiple times with a `continue` or seemingly equal conditions.

Everything it needs to be able to do is to parse a CSV into lines and columns. Reading files, verifying equal column count in each line or using headers for `DataTable`s are jobs that other modules will take care of.

The interface might look unnecessary but I need it for dependency injection and mocking/testing.

```
public interface ICsvParser
{
    IEnumerable<List<string>> Parse(string csv, char separator = ';');
}

public class CsvParser : ICsvParser
{
    public IEnumerable<List<string>> Parse(string csv, char separator = ';')
    {
        if (csv == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csv)); }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(csv)) { yield break; }

        var doubleQuote = '"';
        var carriageReturn = '\r';
        var lineFeed = '\n';
        var eof = false;

        var i = 0;

    resume:

        var isQuote = false;
        var isEscapeSequence = false;
        var isLineBreak = false;

        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        var line = new List<string>();

        for (; i < csv.Length; i++)
        {
            var current = csv[i];

            if (isLineBreak)
            {
                if (current == lineFeed)
                {
                    i++; // Skip the line-feed.
                    goto yield;
                }

                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid character at {i}. Expected '\\n' but found '{current}'.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (isEscapeSequence)
                {
                    if (current == doubleQuote)
                    {
                        buffer.Append(current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isQuote = !isQuote;
                        if (current == separator)
                        {
                            line.Add(buffer.ToString());
                            buffer.Clear();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer.Append(current);
                        }
                    }

                    isEscapeSequence = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (current == doubleQuote)
                    {
                        isEscapeSequence = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (current == separator && !isQuote)
                        {
                            line.Add(buffer.ToString());
                            buffer.Clear();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (current == carriageReturn)
                            {
                                isLineBreak = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                buffer.Append(current);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        eof = true;

    yield:

        // Current buffer is not added yet.
        line.Add(buffer.ToString());

        yield return line;

        if (!eof)
        {
            goto resume;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Example

```
// test data
var csv = new[]
{
    "foo;bar",
    "baz;qux",
    "\"foo;foo\";qux",
    "foo\"\";\"\"bar",
    "\"foo;\"\"foo\";qux",
    ";",
}
.Join("\r\n"); // my helper extension

var csvParser = new CsvParser();
csvParser.Parse(csv).Dump();
csvParser.Parse("").Dump();
```

Output:

```
foo 
bar 

baz 
qux 

foo;foo 
qux 

foo" 
"bar 

foo;"foo 
qux 

<empty>
<empty>
```

`<empty>` is just a placeholder I used here to indicate empty strings.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70813/discussion-on-question-by-t3chb0t-parsing-rfc-4180-csv-with-gotos).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) I would save constants (`doubleQuote`, etc.) as fields, so they don't take up extra space in already fairly large method body.

2) I think your use of `goto` is fine. However you can also rewrite it without `goto`. At first glance it boils down to:

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder();
var line = new List<string>();
foreach(var ch in csv)
{
    var newLine = IsNewLine(ch);

    if (!newLine && TryAppend(ch, buffer, ...)) continue;

    line.Add(buffer.ToString())
    buffer.Clear();

    if (newLine)
    {
        yield return line;
        line = new List<string>();
    }
}

if (line.Any()) yield return line;
```

which also looks fine and is a bit easier to read if you ask me.

3) Alternatively you can go further with gotos and use them as full-fledged state machine. It will allow you to easily remove common sections such as

```
line.Add(buffer.ToString());
buffer.Clear();
```

and deep if-else nests will probably go away as well.

Comment: I pick options 1 & 3 :-) and I totaly missed this redundancy... although I don't know yet how to rewrite it so that it's both nice looking and yet not overcomplicted.

Comment: Or just use `'"'` directly instead of `doubleQuote`. Variables like `var theLetterA = 'A';`does not remove a "magic constant".

Comment: @Eric OTOH, it does allow you to insert inside jokes such as `t_paamayim_nekudotayim` as an alias for `::`.

Comment: Good point on `doubleQuote`. I think `escapeChar` would be a better name.

Comment: @JohnDvorak, pretty sure the correct spelling is Nekuda.. Nekudatayim.

Comment: @DragandDrop PHP and by extension Google think otherwise

Comment: I accept this answer because it's the most open-minded one. I don't think the GOTO in my question is that bad but the other answers boil down to "no goto at all costs" which I find is rather extreme. I also think the nested `if`s are much easier to read and to follow then the mixed `switch/if` suggested in other answers/comments.

Answer (score 12):

The biggest problem with gotos is that they make it really hard to refactor code easily.

Your loop body alone is 66 lines of code long and has a nesting depth of 5. Length of code and nesting depth are two of the prime indicators of complexity and are pretty good indicators for bugs.

To reduce both of those metrics you usually break up your one large method into smaller methods that do one specific thing. And that's exactly where gotos cause trouble: It's impossible to easily refactor your code because it's very tightly interwoven, in this case it's even worse because we jump *outside* the loop body so we actually have to look at the whole method which is over 100 (!) characters long.

Compare this to Nikita's pseudo code. It has 
- 12 lines of code and 
- nesting depth of 2

This does not mean that the complete code including all the separate methods would be shorter (it certainly would have less nesting depth though), but you can now understand each method on its own without having to worry about more low-level details of the others.

PS: And on a performance point of view, gotos have the additional disadvantage that they complicate the control flow graph which means that some compilers might generate worse code - particularly since it's a rarely used feature so not much time goes into improving code that uses it.

Comment: It's really hard to decide what is less wrong, a goto or introducing redundancy. Without going you'll have two returns. This isn't pretty either.

Comment: @t3chb0t Having a single return statement duplicated is hardly a big deal. Redundancy is a problem if you duplicate complex logic because it means you have to change the code at multiple points - that's not really a problem with a single statement.  Not being able to read the whole method on my 30" monitor on the other hand would cause me to reject the code during code reviews. It's really, *really* hard to understand a method if you have to scroll around to understand the control flow.

Comment: Part of this nesting depth is due to the bizarre avoidance of the `else if` construct

Comment: @Eric yup, becase I find it's extremely hard to read and follow. I'd rather use a GOTO than an `else if` ;-] with it, the code looks like all logic was at the same level. Avoiding `else if` very quickly reveals  patterns that you can much easier refactor into separate methods or whatever. You also avoid the same condition in multiple places which further reduces redundancy an makes the overall logic easier to understand. So yes, additional nesting is in this case a positive side-effect.

Comment: @Eric trying to avoid nesting at all costs is equally unwise as doing this with a `goto` or as some people do with LINQ (because they've heard it could be slow). There is a place for everything if there is a good reason for doing something. Nothing has only disadvantages if it's carefulyl designed so sometimes there might be some trade-offs but they might be neglectable if compared with the benefits.

Comment: At the very least, I'd argue that `if (isLineFeed) ... else if(isEscapeSequence) ... else` should all be at the same level, since (I sure hope) they're mutually exclusive

Comment: @t3chb0t A parser by definition will have a long list of branches somewhere, simply to describe all the different branches of its grammar. There is absolutely nothing wrong with it and it's actually what people expect. It makes the code consistent and easy to extend. Just for fun go ahead and introduce comments (say `/* comment*/`) to your code and see how much of it you have to rewrite. That's another consequence of it being very entangled - for larger parsers this way just doesn't scale.

Comment: As far as I know there are not comments in CSV so I'm not really considering introducing this ;-) We'll talk about it when the question is about something that actually requries the parser to understand them - here however this argument is off-topic and violates the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle.

Comment: @t3chb0t Being able to easily maintain and extend code is a hallmark of good code quality. That simple thought experiment will show you one example (apart from the more objective metrics) of how it falls a bit short of that. If your question here is not about whether your code is good or what the problems with it are, what is it about?

Comment: Of course it's about whether the code is good but I don't have to automatically agree with every other point of view. I value and upvote them all and I appreciate all answers but sometimes they are not convincing enough. I always gladly adapt a new way of writing code if I see there are benefits in doing so. I also like being controversial and break the rules by experimenting with new patterns instead of blindly following the well established ones.

Comment: @t3chb0t The whole idea behind the experiment is to let you find out yourself the advantages and disadvantages of that code. I'm sure we all agree that extensibility and maintainability are one of the most important things one can strive for. So doing exactly that (finding out how easy it is to adapt and extend the code) will give you very important insights into how well it really works: How hard is it to the find spots you have to adapt? Do you have to adapt more than one part of your code? Did your changes break other independent parts of the code? And so on.

Answer (score 5):

My rule of thumb is **if you can avoid `goto` then you should avoid it**.

If you want to avoid `if..elseif` but you don't want to have deeply nested `if..else` you could take a `switch` instead.

I would switch the condition of `if (current == separator && !isQuote)` to first check `isQuote == false` as well.

Using a `switch` and implementing @NikitaB's answer part about the const chars will look like

```
public class CsvParser : ICsvParser
{
    private const char doubleQuote = '"';
    private const char carriageReturn = '\r';
    private const char lineFeed = '\n';
    public IEnumerable<List<string>> Parse(string csv, char separator = ';')
    {
        if (csv == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csv)); }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(csv)) { yield break; }

        var isQuote = false;
        var isEscapeSequence = false;
        var isLineBreak = false;

        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        var line = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < csv.Length; i++)
        {
            var current = csv[i];
            switch (current)
            {

                case (lineFeed):
                    line.Add(buffer.ToString());
                    yield return line;

                    isQuote = false;
                    isEscapeSequence = false;
                    isLineBreak = false;
                    buffer.Clear();
                    line.Clear();
                    break;

                case (doubleQuote):
                    if (isEscapeSequence)
                    {
                        buffer.Append(current);
                    }
                    isEscapeSequence = !isEscapeSequence;
                    break;

                case (carriageReturn):
                    isLineBreak = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    if (isLineBreak)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid character at {i}. Expected '\\n' but found '{current}'.");
                    }
                    if (isEscapeSequence)
                    {
                        isQuote = !isQuote;
                        isEscapeSequence = false;
                    }
                    if (isQuote == false && current == separator)
                    {
                        line.Add(buffer.ToString());
                        buffer.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buffer.Append(current);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
        line.Add(buffer.ToString());

        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to see a switch in action ;-) though still thinking my code is prettier and easier to follow. With a flat structure it's not so easy to see in which mode you currently are in - that's why I avoid `else if`, I like it less then the `goto` :-]  You also need to guard other conditions when execution path does not match previous `if`s. With simple `if/else` there are no such situations so it's less error-prone.

Comment: @t3chb0t, IMHO this implementation is easier to read. It is a state machine and it reads as a state machine: for linebreak - do this, for doublequote - do that, etc. Some of the "states" are not immediately apparent, but most are (for example `doublequote+isEscapeSequence` state is hard to represent as separate switch case). On the other hand, when I look at your implementation,  it is way harder to tell "what happens when parser finds a doublequote", because this logic is separated into different if-else branches. It is not isolated from other states and it cannot be understood in isolation.

Comment: P.S. I agree, that goto-based solution can be shorter and single return is an advantage. I'm not sure it's worth it though. Voo summed up the disadvantages very well.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten the `CsvParser` multiple times and this is its 5-th incarnation.    It became a `CsvReader` that now works with a `TextReader` so that I don't have to load the entire csv-file in order to parse it. I removed the GOTOs and extracted the new `ReadFieldAsync` method that now contains the logic. There is also a new helper method `MoveNext` that now advances the current position. I tried to create an enumerator for the stream but it does not support an `async` API so I dropped this idea.

```
public interface ICsvReader : IDisposable
{
    Task<IList<string>> ReadLineAsync();
}

public class CsvReader : ICsvReader
{
    private const char doubleQuote = '"';
    private const char carriageReturn = '\r';
    private const char lineFeed = '\n';
    private const int charCount = 1;
    private const int noCharRead = 0;

    private readonly TextReader _csv;
    private readonly char _separator;
    private readonly char[] _current = new char[1];
    private int _position;
    private bool _isEndOfLine;
    private bool _isEndOfStream;

    public CsvReader(TextReader csv, char separator = ';')
    {
        _csv = csv;
        _separator = separator;
    }

    public CsvReader(string csv, Encoding encoding, char separator = ';')
    : this(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(csv))), separator)
    {
    }

    public CsvReader(string csv, char separator = ';')
    : this(csv, Encoding.UTF8, separator)
    {
    }

    private char Current => _current[0];

    public Task<IList<string>> ReadLineAsync()
    {
        if (_isEndOfStream)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((IList<string>)null); ;
        }

        _isEndOfLine = false;

        var line =
            enumerable
                .Always(async () => await ReadFieldAsync())
                .TakeWhile(field => field.Result != null)
                .Select(t => t.Result)
                .ToList();

        return Task.FromResult((IList<string>)line);
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadFieldAsync()
    {
        if (_isEndOfStream || _isEndOfLine)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var isQuoted = false;
        var field = new StringBuilder();

        while (await MoveNextAsync())
        {
            if (Current == doubleQuote)
            {
                // Ignore the first double-quote.
                if (!await MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    return field.ToString();
                }

                // Double-quote not followed by another double-quote means the filed is quoted.
                if (Current != doubleQuote)
                {
                    isQuoted = !isQuoted;
                }
            }

            // Use only not-quoted separators for splitting.
            if (Current == _separator && !isQuoted)
            {
                return field.ToString();
            }

            if (Current == carriageReturn && !isQuoted)
            {
                // Ignore carragie-return.
                if (!await MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Missing line-feed at {_position}.");
                }

                if (Current == lineFeed)
                {
                    _isEndOfLine = true;
                    return field.ToString();
                }

                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid character at {_position}. Expected '\\n' (line-feed) but found '{Current}'.");
            }

            field.Append(Current);
        }

        return field.ToString();
    }

    private async Task<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        if (!_isEndOfStream)
        {
            _position++;
        }

        // Read one character at a time.
        return !(_isEndOfStream = await _csv.ReadAsync(_current, 0, charCount) == noCharRead);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _csv.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The helper extension `Always` that I use here is implemented as:

```
public static class enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Always<T>(Func<T> get)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return get();
        }
    }
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
var csv = new[]
{
    "foo;bar",
    "baz;qux",
    "\"foo;foo\";qux",
    "foo\"\";\"\"bar",
    "\"foo;\"\"foo\";qux",
    ";",
}
.Join("\r\n");

using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(csv))
{
    enumerable
        .Always(async () => await csvReader.ReadLineAsync())
        .TakeWhile(line => line.Result != null)
        .Select(line => line.Result)
        .Dump();
}
```